# How can I generate select options for all my JSON object keys?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, input

So I've got an input field in which takes data from a locally stored json file. The data becomes options for the user to pick from when "searching in the field". Instead of writing the 100+ results one by one like I am doing.. Is there a faster and better way of doing this? I also get a minor error in the console "Cannot read property '1' of undefined" but my method "works", but it's bad code.

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" list="datalist2"/>
<datalist id ="datalist2">
    <option  *ngIf="town_list">
    <option value="{{town_list[1].bc}}">
    <option value="{{town_list[2].bc}}">
    <option value="{{town_list[3].bc}}">

</datalist>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using \*ngfor for options in select element using nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42014286/using-ngfor-for-options-in-select-element-using-nested-json)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `*ngFor`. That way you can iterate through array and display every item in there.

```
<option *ngFor="let town of town_list" ngValue="town.bc">{{town.bc}}</option>
```

https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data#showing-an-array-property-with-ngfor

Comment: I've tried to use it but I can't seem to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Use `*ngIf` to check if the array is good, but if you want to iterate over it, you need `*ngFor`

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" list="datalist2"/>
<datalist id ="datalist2" *ngIf="town_list">
    <option *ngFor="let town of town_list">{{town.bc}} </option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to copy your answer however it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @Durutelefon1 any message or clue why it doesnt work?

Comment: @Durutelefon1 I updated it, it shoudl work now...try

Comment: I'll give u the solve thingy when the timer runs out! Thanks!